# Error when trying to include css animation svg in a react app

Tags: css, reactjs, svg

I am trying to include a css animation svg in a react app created with create-react-app.
the code looks more or less like this:

```
import Bla from './animaded_css.svg'

[...]

<Bla/>
```

However, I get this error:

```
Error: Expected node, got `#ekE9RuALNbm6 {animation: ekE9RuALNbm6_c_o 3000ms linear infinite normal forwards}@keyframes ekE9RuALNbm6_c_o { 0% {opacity: 1} 16.666667% {opacity: 1;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 33.333333% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 66.666667% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 83.333333% {opacity: 1} 100% {opacity: 1}} #ekE9RuALNbm7 {animation: ekE9RuALNbm7_c_o 3000ms linear infinite normal forwards}@keyframes ekE9RuALNbm7_c_o { 0% {opacity: 1;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 16.666667% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 50% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 66.666667% {opacity: 1} 100% 
{opacity: 1}} #ekE9RuALNbm8 {animation: ekE9RuALNbm8_c_o 3000ms linear infinite normal forwards}@keyframes ekE9RuALNbm8_c_o { 0% {opacity: 1} 33.333333% {opacity: 1;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 50% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 83.333333% {opacity: 0;animation-timing-function: cubic-bezier(0.42,0,1,1)} 100% {opacity: 1}}`        
    at one (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\one.js:12:11)
    at all (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\all.js:20:37)
    at element (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\handlers.js:51:37)
    at one (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\one.js:19:10)
    at all (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\all.js:20:37)
    at element (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\handlers.js:51:37)
    at one (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\one.js:19:10)
    at all (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\all.js:20:37)
    at root (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\handlers.js:20:54)
    at one (C:\code\Tests\app\node_modules\react-scripts\node_modules\@svgr\hast-util-to-babel-ast\lib\one.js:19:10)
 @ ./src/App.tsx 6:0-35 14:38-41
 @ ./src/index.tsx 7:0-24 12:33-36
```

I can however display the image directly in the browser so I guess there are no fatal problems with the .svg-File itself.

I installed `file-loader` and `@svgr/webpack` but am getting the very same error.

Comment: Maybe try to import the SVG as a `ReactComponent` like so `import { ReactComponent as Bla } from "./animated_css.svg";`. Or, since you are using `file-loader`try to reconfigure the import statement itself like `import Bla from "!file-loader!./animated_css.svg";` - see https://giters.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/11770 for further details

Comment: had tried, the same error.

Comment: Importing SVG's in a React project can be an absolute pain. Not sure about your project and how complicated it is already but maybe consider using a library like Chakra UI for generating SVG components. This works for me pretty well. https://chakra-ui.com - sorry, for not having a better answer here!

Comment: thank you. maybe I resort to it if I find no other solution. In fact I have no idea about .svg animation files - maybe I am not including it the right way, maybe there's an easy solution.

Comment: I thing it's not the animation but the way you include the SVG into your project. Webpack does not parse it properly (I've ran into this issue numerous times). Does it happen with non-animated SVGs too?

Comment: First - thank you for taking your time. What about a chat, would be faster? I have downloaded some simple sample svg animations and tried to on my page and they work. the "problem" animation file contains style-tag inside svg and apparently this style tag causes an error.

Comment: Unfortunately, I have to go now but maybe try this tool: https://jakearchibald.github.io/svgomg/ - you have a lot of options to clean up your SVG and safe it optimised for web. Saved my life a couple of times already!

Comment: Cheers and once again thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was that the content of `<style>` within `<svg>` was wrapped within a `<[CDATA`. Apparently (some?) browsers can deal with it but React cannot.